# Slidify centering the title page

Tags: html, css, slidify

I am working for the first time with slidify and I would like to alter the layout of the homepage by centering the title, subtitle, author and job.
By adding text-align:center; to the css, I was able to get them centered regarding each other.  But I can only manage to get them in the center of my slide by adding left: 480px;.  But off course, now the alignment is suboptimal since it changes whenever the length of my title changes.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post your relevant code, we can't help without it

Answer (score 0):

In the default css, I've changed the settings to this

```
/* line 924, ../scss/default.scss */
.title-slide group {
bottom: 55px;
left: 480px;
text-align: center;
}
```